# FCM Custom Notification Icon not displayed

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, notification-icons

I have created white/transparent PNG notification icons and added them in `application` meta-data in AndroidManifest as per the manuals.

The strange thing is that the custom icon is displayed correctly on Samsung Mini (jelly bean) and Nexus 4 (API 27) emulator, but not on Samsung A6 (Oreo) and Huawei Honor Lite 9 (Oreo) devices where I see the default white droid on green background icon.

The notification is always displayed but on some devices the custom icon is not used.

I tried to implement it in AssetStudio and also implemented with and without Notification Builder but it had not effect.

Answer (score 0):

For Oreo you need to implement notification channels: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

Also you should put default default_notification_channel_id inside the AndroidManifest: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: while this answer can give help it's always better to put the relevant code in the post and give the link only as reference

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by using the latest versions of Google Play and Firebase libraries. I had a slightly outdated Google Play version.

Answer (score 0):

set this to your application tag in Manifest:

```
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_your_default_logo" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a transparent icon. To test download any [png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gb6ek.png) , colorAccent is `#ff7800` for my example

- Add these lines in `manifest.file`

  ```
  <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" 
  android:resource="@drawable/icon8" />

  <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color" 
  android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
  ```

These changes will help in icon display.

Comment: Where do you set that color of colorAccent ?